# Difference between dependent and independent clauses

Tags: grammar, differences, conjunctions, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

In the sentence "It's raining, but I'm happy," "but" is a coordinating conjunction. Both of the clauses are independent, right?

However, doesn't "I'm happy even though it's raining" mean the same thing? And yet, in this case, "even though it's raining" is a dependent clause, correct, because "even though" is a subordinating conjunction?

So I'm confused. What's the difference between dependent and independent clauses? I'm a secondary English teacher and I'm not sure how to explain this apparent double standard.

Comment: I take "though" to be  a preposition, with the declarative content clause "it's raining" as its complement. The clause has no internal marker of subordination: it is shown to be subordinate by virtue of its function in the larger construction

Comment: In general dependent clauses headed by subordinators such as _because, though, since, before, etc._ can precede or follow the independent clause without changing any words or the meaning (although fronting a dependent clause gives it slightly more prominence). So, _"I'm happy even though it's raining"_ = _"Even though it's raining, I'm happy"_. This does not work for successive independent clauses: "_?But I'm happy, it's raining"_.

Comment: @Shoe, how does that connect to the idea of a _dependent clause_ as not representing a complete thought and not being able to form a complete sentence on its own? Or do linguists define _dependent clause_ differently?

Answer (score 2):

Whether a clause is dependent or independent doesn't have to do with its meaning. That's where the confusion about *but* with *even though* came from. They **do** mean sort of the same thing.

But that fact doesn't have anything to do with whether they introduce dependent or independent clauses. 
*Dependent* means 'hanging from' in Latin, and the idea is that one clause is the main one,
while others hang from it, and are marked as 'subordinate' (another `UP/DOWN` metaphor) to it.

> This is why syntax uses upside-down "tree" diagrams to illustrate sentence structure.
>   Just a bunch of phrases and clauses hanging around together, like aerialists on a break.

For instance, the subordinate clause can be like an adverb modifying a verb phrase,

- ***Because she had already started***, she finished it.

or like a direct object of a verb

- *I told him **that she would finish it***.

There are coordinating conjunctions (*and, but, or,* and (rarely) *for*) that hook together two independent sentences, and they can go on forever:

- *Bill saw Sue, and Mary told Joan, and Joan was mad, but Mary just laughed, or maybe not...*

However, except for those, **every** other clause introducer -- every conjunction or adverb or phrase or marker or relative pronoun or preposition or complementizer -- and there are literally thousands of these in English -- introduces a subordinate, i.e, **dependent**, clause. They are overwhelmingly more common than independent clauses.

So the vast majority of sentences in English are the kind that are called "complex", because they contain at least one subordinate, i.e. dependent, clause in addition to a main, i.e. independent, clause.

Comment: But what accounts for the special status enjoyed by "but", "or", and "for"? Certainly a declarative sentence with two clauses joined by "and" is asserting the truth of the proposition represented by each clause independently. But to my mind, every other conjunction, including e.g. "but", indicates a dependent relationship between the cause the conjunction begins and some other clause of the sentence.

Comment: +1. Indeed, excellent so! *They **do** mean **sort** of the same thing*, they are very much alike, but not identical.

Comment: _But_ is the same as _and_, semantically; they both conjoin assertions and have the same truth table. _But_ has an additional presupposition about surprise; but it's still just _and_ with a pragmatic assist. As for what's special about them, they're the logician's favorite dyadic functors: **ʌ** 'and', **v** 'or'. With them and negation, no others are needed. See the [Logic Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Logicguide.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can say independent clauses are the ones that have a meaning even though they are said alone. If I say “I am happy” you get that I am happy.
Dependent clauses instead have no meaning if they are said alone. If I say “even though is raining” you get that it’s raining but the sentence has no meaning since there isn’t a main clause.

Comment: But couldn't you say the same for "But I'm happy," an independent clause?

Comment: Of course, “but I’m happy” is a dependent clause. It means nothing used alone... you have to remove “but” or add a main clause

Comment: @Jay It's typically the *syntax* that determines how a sentence is analyzed. When everything is equal, and syntax isn't enough, I will look at the *semantics*. The difference between the two sentences you've given has to do with how they are *constructed* (which is different), not with what is trying to be expressed (which is the same).

Comment: @Marybnq Actually, the existence of a conjunction *doesn't* mean that what comes after isn't an independent clause. Typically, you *join* two independent clauses with a conjunction and a comma (otherwise it's a comma splice). In this case, I would say that the first version of the sentence *does* have two independent clauses, while the second version does not.

Comment: @JasonBassford of course, but if I add a conjunction to the beginning of an independent clause it becomes dependent one  as you can’t start a sentence with a conjunction as it would need another clause to have a meaning. Of course I know that what comes after the conjunction can be an independent clause, I wasn’t saying that...

Comment: *And who says you can't start a sentence with a conjunction?* It's a grammar myth that you can't. ;) Typically, it needs to join with something that came before. (In this case, I presume it's my previous comment.) But it's [completely normal](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_27.htm) to have two independent clauses in a single sentence, joined by a conjunction. Doing so does not magically make the two into a single clause. (Note that I'm not actually disagreeing with the answer you gave.)

Comment: "But" and "even though" do not mean the same thing in your sentences. And do  not have the same function in your sentences.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest terms.

> Two independent clauses:
>
> He eats ham but I eat jam.
>
> Two independent clauses joined by BUT: He eats ham. I eat jam. That is, each can stand alone if you remove the conjunction.

Compare that to:

> Two clauses, one independent and one dependent.
>
> He eats ham even though I eat jam.
>
> even though is a dependent clause introducer (see John Lawler above).

Even though introduces the idea that "I eat jam". It is not a conjunction.

[May I say that even though I eat jam, I am not happy? joke]

Comment: I think your previous comment should be part of the answer, it's a good one, anyway +1.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm happy* [*even though it's raining*].

Independent clauses and dependent ones are not distinguished by meaning. Usually, there is some grammatical marker such as a subordinator like "that", "whether" or "if".

But the bracketed clause has no internal marker of subordination ("even" is an adverb and "though" is a preposition. Nevertheless, the clause is shown to be subordinate by virtue of its function in the larger construction.